# Set Google +1 button url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking, google-plus-one

I am building an image gallery that is slider based and loads new images via javascript and have a requirement to set the Google +1 button's URL via javascript so +1 can be set on each image.

I also need to reload the +1 button based on each image (the url will have a querystring parameter containing the image id to make it unique). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-href="#"></div>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

You can use the following code to alter the gplus href attribute using jQuery. Make sure to include jquery library first and then use the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(".your-button").click(function(){
       jQuery(".g-plusone").attr("data-href","Your-Value-Goes-Here");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this in head tag:

```
// Load +1 script
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

The HTML Code:

```
<div id="plusone_container">

</div>
```

And write this jQuery anywhere you want to set +1 button's url:

```
    $("#plusone_container").html('<div id="plusone"></div>');
    gapi.plusone.render("plusone", { "href": "Your URL" });
```